# "Mom comes" Is it grammatical?

Tags: grammar

My English teachers says you have to follow grammar, else/otherwise your English won't improve. But I don't see people speaking/writing grammatically correct English, here is a little example: I was talking last night with my friend (native English speaker) and suddenly our conversation got stopped. Today our conversation starts

Me: what happened? My-friend: Mom comes

Can you explain if this is grammatical?

Answer (score 8):

Your teachers are not being 'fraudulent'. As a student of a foreign language you have to learn the basics of correct grammar first. Later, as your English becomes more confident you will become familiar with the 'lazy' speech that people use in everyday conversation, and when it is, and is not, appropriate to use it.

Comment: I don't get this answer. Although technically speaking OP's cited Simple Present ***Mom comes*** is "grammatical", I can't imagine any context where a native speaker would actually say that rather than ***Mom's coming!***

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Yes, I thought **Mom comes** a rather peculiar thing for a native speaker to say, but I was just addressing the OP's grievance. (He didn't originally ask whether it was grammatical, but seemed to imply that he thought it wasn't.)

Answer (score 1):

OP's example ***Mom comes***! is obviously "grammatical", but *in practice*, native speakers rarely use Simple Present to describe something *currently happening*.

I'm assuming that in the *specific* context, the friend is *warning / informing* OP that his mother is approaching *because this affects their ongoing conversation* (because she'll divert the friend's attention, they don't want her to overhear private discussions, or whatever). We almost *always* use Present Continuous in such situations...

> A: *What happened?*
>    B: *[Shush!] Mom's **coming**!*  - so **be careful** what you say!

This strong preference for Present *Continuous* also applies in other contexts. For example...

> A: (On the phone) *What's the weather like where you are?*
>    B: ***It's raining***
>   (never ***It rains***)